# Отредактировать текст в терминале linux

Tags: linux, терминал, работа-с-текстом

Имеется текстовый документ data.txt вида:

```
QF4LiSgs2;0
2cUwRU3fBw;1
hjM4i9Hh813dLCNx2Sy;53000
```

подскажите команду в терминале linux чтобы удалить из него только те строки, где после разделителя `;` значится `0` (там только целое неотрицательное число), или все, что содержат `1` и более
спасибо

Comment: а открыть редактором (vim/emacs) и поправить? Или нужна команда на sed/awk?

Comment: нужна команда на sed/awk

Comment: или все, что содержат 1 и более. то есть все числа больше 0. так?

Comment: все строки,  что содержат 1 и более после ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте команду sed:

```
sed -e '/;0/d' -- my.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: работает, спасибо!

Comment: @Bl0wfish если вам помог ответ отметьте его правильным

Comment: только лучше использовать наверно `-i`,  а не перенаправлять вывод.

Comment: @KoVadim, тогда уж ключик для создания резервной копии не забудьте на всякий случай. И версию программы проверить перед вызовом... Уже в который раз твержу — shell не для новичков.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat data.txt  | egrep -v ".*1.*;" | egrep  ";0$" > data.txt
```

исключить строки, которые содержат 1 до знака ;
после показывать те строки, которые содержат только 0 после знака ;

```
user@pc:/tmp$ cat test
QF4LiSgs2;0
2cUwRU3fBw;1
hjM4i9Hh813dLCNx2Sy;53000
dfsdsf;3
ds1;2
cdscsd5;43
user@pc:/tmp$ cat test  | egrep -v ".*1.*;" | egrep  ";0$"
QF4LiSgs2;0
```

Comment: Useless use of cat.

Comment: почему это? файл-то не большой. можно, конечно, сразу в grep передать

Comment: По вашему коду. Я не знаю, зачем вы написали бессмысленный вызов *cat*. В shell так не принято.

Comment: А слова в моём первом комментарии являются идиомой. Погуглите.